# ASP.NET MVC5: Unable to add new roles with custom db context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, argumentnullexception

I'm having a really disgusting problem with custom db context of my ASP.NET MVC project.

Well I've been trying merge the auto-generated `ApplicationDbContext` with my own `GSDbContext` while still keeping `IdentityUsers` and `IdentityRoles` working.

This is my custom `ApplicationUser` class definition:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstAndLastName { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

And context class:

```
public class GSDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
     public GSDbContext()
          : base("GSDbContext")
     {
     }

     public virtual IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
     public virtual IDbSet<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }
     public virtual IDbSet<IdentityUserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }
     public virtual IDbSet<IdentityUserClaim> UserClaims { get; set; }
     public virtual IDbSet<IdentityUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Now what happens is that when I try to add a new Role, I get `System.ArgumentNullException`. BTW, I can easily create a new user with no bloody pain. I use this code to create a new user:

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
            new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new GSDbContext()));
userManager.Create(user, password);
```

And for adding a new role:

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new GSDbContext()));
roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
```

Which throws the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
  Source=System.Core
  ParamName=source
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`1.ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary`2 items)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()
       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.RoleStore`1.<CreateAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManager`1.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManagerExtensions.Create[TRole](RoleManager`1 manager, TRole role)
```

Which has driven me pretty much crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the properties which are already existing in IdentityDbContext.

```
public class GSDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
     public GSDbContext()
          : base("GSDbContext")
     {
     }
     public virtual IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
     //Nothing ELSE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't include identity models to your `DbContext` which is already included by `IdentityDbContext` itself. So you could change your context like this:

```
public class GSDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // put your OTHER entities apart from identity related onces
    public IDbSet<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; }
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the case.
Although I get the multiple IEntityChangeTracker issue when using UserManager along with my context, but I handled that problem by not using it and use direct LINQ instead.

Comment: This is happening because of you have multiple instance of your `DbContext` in same time. If you want submit a question about the issue with relevant code and tell me. I will answer it.

Comment: Nope, I got it fixed. Thanks anyway.